# Laravel sometimes validation rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to validate a password field only if it is present. I want to allow someone to edit a user and they may or may not want to change the users password. So I thought I could this using Laravels validation rules, specifically the 'sometimes' rule. I have this set of rules:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'sometimes|required|min:8',
]);
```

This is simplified for the example, there will usually be other rules for other fields and stricter rules for the password. I expect this to only apply the min:8 rule if the password field is present in the passed data, but if I leave the password field empty I get a validation error saying the password field is required.

I'm not sure what I'm not understanding in the docs. Do I need to manually remove the password field before validation if it is the form input was submitted empty like this?

```
$data = $request->all();

if ('' === $data['password']) {
    unset($data['password'])
}
```

...and then pass the array into the validator. I think this makes sense but I could do with some confirmation that I'm understanding it correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the docs, that's what i understand. So, basically you are good to go unless anyone tells otherwise.

Comment: It also seems that if you remove the required rule, it works fine like this: 'sometimes|min:8.....', but the docs don't really make this clear.

Comment: Yup. that's what i thought first, then checked the docs again. :D

Comment: I saw a comment saying to do that so I did, then the comment vanished, was that you?

Comment: yup. that was me. anyway glad could help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docs don't make it clear, But removing required makes it work.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:8',
]);
```

Comment: Seems obvious really but the docs direct you away from the solution. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: Yup, did it on code but got confused seeing docs. glad could help :)

Comment: Do I understand that right? The sometimes rule means that the input are optional ?

Comment: "In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field 
only if that field is present in the input array.". I think this is clear enough

Answer (score 19):

I think we should tell laravel If password is not empty put the rules otherwise do nothing.

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'password' => $request->password != null ?'sometimes|required|min:8': ''
]);
```

Comment: "In the example above, the password field will only be validated if it is present in the $data array". from the docs

Comment: @nbin  Could you reference it?

Comment: I did read that in the docs but I didn't feel that manually removing something form the array seemed a good way of doing it. Plus you couldn't then use a custom Request for the validation rules.

Comment: @nbin What actually `$data` is then? An array of data so yeah request is having all those stuff inside..

Comment: @Steven1978 I agree that it will not work with `Custom Request` but I don't see any other away around

Comment: @BasheerAhmed $data is a variable. My point is, Docs says if post array doesn't contain $password field it won't validate it.

Answer (score 7):

> "I am trying to validate a password field only if it is present."

To do this, you can use the "nullable" rule within the validation system.

For example:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'sometimes|nullable|min:8',
]);
```

For more information take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation section under "A Note On Optional Fields"

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but there's a lot of confusion in the answers above. This is currently the first result on Google for "sometimes validation rule", so I hope I can clarify things a bit for fellow googlers:

Rule `sometimes` works like this:

- If the field exists in the request, validate it with the rest of rules;
- If the field doesn't exist do nothing.

Note that **doesn't exist** means that the field **never got submitted** (`isset($_POST['password']) === false`), it's not the same as a field being submitted with an empty string or null or 0 value - therefore
`'sometimes|required|min:8'` will work only if the form has no password field at all, or it's disabled so that it's never submitted.

If password field is there, just left empty and then form gets submitted, we will still get `'password' => null` and for `sometimes` it means it exists, so the rest of the rules will be applied (and since required field can't be null the request will fail).

What OP really needs is:

```
'password' => 'nullable|min:8',
```

Presuming that password field will always be present in the request, just sometimes its value can be left empty.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's generally safer to allow the user to change its password only if he can provided the old one.

Allowing the connected user to alter his password without providing the old one can be a security issue.

This is generally how I allow user password change with Laravel:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'user.old_password' => [],
            'user.password' => [
                'required_with:user.old_password',
                'min:6',
                'confirmed',
                'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*([-+_!@#$%^&*.,;?])).+$/',
                'different:user.old_password'
            ],
            'user.password_confirmation' => ['required_with:user.password'],
        ]);
```

This don't validate the old password as we don't care, the database will check it for us, but I validate the new password only if the old one is provided.

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode you fill password field by for example "********" and in update mode validate like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'required|min:8',
]);
```

and in controller check `$data['password']='********'` find old password and

```
$data['password']='old password in db'
```

and `$data['password']!='********'` 
update pssword

Answer (score 2):

As an option to the selected answer, you can use:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
       'password' => 'nullable|min:8',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This notation would be useful:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'password' => Rule::when(request()->has('password'), ['required','min:6']),
    ]);
```

which uses `Illuminate\Validation\Rule`

Answer (score 0):

**If value is present then it will check minimum  length. It'll work 100% in laravel 6.18**

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'user_id' => 'sometimes|nullable|min:5'
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel sometimes validation rule and their function:

**accepted**
The field under validation must be yes, on, 1, or true. This is useful for validating "Terms of Service" acceptance.

**active_url**
The field under validation must have a valid A or AAAA record according to the dns_get_record PHP function.

**after:date**
The field under validation must be a value after a given date. The dates will be passed into the  strtotime PHP function:
'start_date' => 'required|date|after:tomorrow'
Instead of passing a date string to be evaluated by strtotime, you may specify another field to compare against the date:
'finish_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date'

**after_or_equal:date**
The field under validation must be a value after or equal to the given date. For more information, see the after rule.

**alpha**
The field under validation must be entirely alphabetic characters.