# Laravel Dynamic Input Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm developing an application, where I'm creating dynamic input. Validation is working properly except one use case.

Validation rule is here:

```
return [
         '*.id' => 'nullable|numeric',
         '*.name' => 'required|min:3|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/|unique:products,name,*.id,id,category_id,'.$this->route('id'),
         '*.quantity_available' => 'nullable|numeric|min:0',
         '*.quantity_sold' => 'nullable|numeric|min:0',
         '*.price'=> 'required|numeric|min:10',
         '*.sale_price' => 'required|numeric|min:10',
       ];
```

Please have a look over the following sent data:

```
{id: 5, category_id: 3, name: "Test 1", description: null, quantity_available: null, quantity_sold: null, price:40, sale_price:35},
{id: 6, category_id: 3, name: "Test 2", description: null, quantity_available: null, quantity_sold: null,price:40, sale_price:35},
{id: "", name: "Test 3", quantity_available: "", quantity_sold: "", price: 40, sale_price: 35}
```

I want the product name to be unique as per the category_id and if a input has id present, then that product id would be ignored while product name unique validation.

Comment: You can checkout to the sometimes validation rule in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196715/laravel-sometimes-validation-rule), maybe it will helps you

Comment: @JulienMetral I have been researching over it from past so many hours. Its little bit complicated due to group input validation.